# asp.net / ext.net : UserControl informing parent of successful or failed operation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, ext.net

I am playing around with EXT.net (ASP.NET) and I have the following situation:

**ParentPage.aspx** - contains a Button that opens an *Ext.net* "Window"; a Popup done with Javascript. In that Window I place a UserControl (Customer.ascx). That UserControl can create Customers and it does so using Ext.NET DirectMethod's in code-behind, Customer.ascx.cs

**Customer.ascx** - The UserControl that contains some Ext.net controls and the code to create the Customer object.

Now, when I call the *DirectMetod* CreateNewCustomer the Customer is created as expected, but now I want the ParentPage to know about this successful (or failed) operation and act accordingly.

So if the operation fails - the Customer cannot be created for some reason - the Window (popup) should stay in place and an error should be displayed. But if the operation succeeds then the Window should be closed and a list should be updated/refreshed.

I can't/should place any "OnSuccess"-code in the UserControl since the UserControl doesn't really know if it is placed in a Window or elsewhere and it shouldn't be up to the UserControl to take decisions if it should be shown or not.

**So I need to inform the ParentPage of what's going on.** My spine-reaction was to have an Event in the UserControl, but that didn't work of course since it is an asynchronous operation and I can't push messages to the web browser.

Maybe one could place a JavaScript method in the ParentPage that the UserControl calls, but that is sort of ugly. The UserControl should be able to inform the parent page in a "secure manner". It doesn't really know if the Javascript method is there, so it could be calling a method that does not exist?

What approaches can I try?

Comment: I have looked into the ScriptManager and wanted to use "RegisterStartupScript" in my DirectMethod in the UserControl. The script should check for another Javascript method called "CustomerReportCallback" and if existed, call that method. That way I could check if the Parent had a Javascript-method that could be used for the "callback" after the operation succeeded. But no success - it seems "RegisterStartupScript" can only be in Page_Load?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I call the DirectMetod CreateNewCustomer the Customer is created as expected, but now I want the ParentPage to know about this successful (or failed) operation and act accordingly.
>
> So if the operation fails - the Customer cannot be created for some
>   reason - the Window (popup) should stay in place and an error should
>   be displayed.

How I would do this, would be to apply the following attributes to my DirectMethod:

```
[DirectMethod(ShowMask = true, SuccessFn = "showSuccessMessage", FailureFn = "showFailureMessage", Msg = "Creating Customer...", RethrowException = true)]
```

and then write client side JS functions for the success/failure of the DirectMethod, one as you say, to close the window, you could make this so that if the window doesn't exist it doesn't do anything to avoid any oddities when you place the UC elswhere.

That does unfortunately force the UC to close itself and perhaps that's not ideal, but it may sort the issue.